# MVC.Net href empty on Url.Action

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, hyperlink

I don't understand the result of my MVC link, created with Url.Action. 
On my DEV IIS, the href link is correct, but on the final server, the href is empty.

On my Dev server, the .Net framework 4.5 is installed, but not in the final server where the .Net framework 4.0 is installed.

My code in my view **MyView** :

This code works :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyView", "MyController", new { project = ViewBag.project, param = ViewBag.param })">Text</a>
```

This code doesn't work :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action2", "MyController", new { project = ViewBag.project, param = ViewBag.param })">Text</a>
```

My route is :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{project}/{param}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyView", project ="", param = "" }
        );
```

Here is my controller : 
Thanks for your answer. Here is my controller code :

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{ 
    public ActionResult MyView(string project, string param) 
    { 
        // Some action 
        return View(); 
    } 

    public ActionResult Action2(string project, string param) 
    { 
        // Some action 
        return View("MyView"); 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand this problem ?
How a href attribute can be empty ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean link for "MyView" action is generating but not for "Action2" on final server? If yes, how is it behaving if you change default "action" from "Action1" to "Action2" in the route template?

Comment: I made a mistake on my code : default action is "MyView"

Comment: So did you try changing "MyView" to "Action2" in the route template and try again?